# Why is my email validation not working in bootstrap and html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form on my page:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <form class="form-horizontal general subscribe" name="commentform" id="subscribe" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 lower">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="email requiredField form-control" name="subscribe_email" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info form_submit" value="Subscribe"/>
    </div>
    <div id="form_results"></div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

and my jquery code for handling the email stuff is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('.form_submit').click(function() {
      var form = $(this).parents('form');

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mywebservice/mail',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          email: $('input[name=subscribe_email]').val()
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response) {
          output = '<p>Thanks, we will contact you soon!</p>';

          $("#contacts_form .form_item").val('');
          form.find('.form_inner').slideUp();
          form.find("#form_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }
     });
     return false;
   });
});
```

and now the email is added successfuly to the database each time user presses the Subscribe button, but the problem is that the email is not validated with an official email pattern. I thought that in html5 the only necessary check is this `<input type="email"` but it does not work properly... How can I prevent users from adding wrong email addresses to the database?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `required` attribute for a field to be `validated`

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="email requiredField form-control" name="subscribe_email" required="required" />
```

If you `submit` the form using normal `submit` button then `required` fields are validated automatically.

If you are `submitting` or calling `javasript function` on `submit` button then
you can use `form.checkValidity()` to validate the `required` controls.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('.form_submit').click(function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        form.checkValidity()
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://mywebservice/mail',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    email: $('input[name=subscribe_email]').val()

                },
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response)
                {
                    output = '<p>Thanks, we will contact you soon!</p>';
                    $("#contacts_form .form_item").val('');
                    form.find('.form_inner').slideUp();
                    form.find("#form_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }
            });
    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Hmm I tried adding `required="required"` and also only `required` , but both didn't work... What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: You only need to pass in `required`, Check my posted answer below

Comment: Ok so when I added `form.checkValidity()` line then in my gui everything works! but in the console I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: form.checkValidity is not a function`

Comment: @user3766930 I would you use a third party jQuery library that handles validation, but `required` i just fine normal email validation

Answer (score 0):

add `required` attribute for `<input type="email"` and sure there is no JavaScript error on the page as well.

Comment: It didn't work :( apparently the script gets called immediately and the record goes to the database without prior validation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `required` attribute as per HTML `input` with `type email` requires that before it can perform any validation.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="email requiredField form-control" name="subscribe_email" required />
```

You can also look into https://jqueryvalidation.org/, I use it and its awesome it allows you show custom message to users